# Half-page prints on Synology DS207+

Tags: printer, nas

I have a HP DeskJet930c printer connected to a Synology NAS DS207+ via USB. When I'm printing I only get half a page printed, then the printing stops and the page is not feed out. I'm using the newest available printer driver and NAS firmware.

Anyone using the same printer? Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could fix this: I used the [Synology Assistant](http://ukdl.synology.com/download/ds/DSAssistant/DSAssistant_844.zip) to install the printer driver and this works fine. Seems Synology uses another driver there.